# make page content not step over a fixed footer

Tags: html, css

On my website I have a fixed footer at the bottom of my page, so it is always visible.

It used to be 30px height so what I did is setting a `margin-bottom: 50px` on the `#container` of every page, this way the content would never be hidden by my footer, and if it went passed the 50px margin mark, then you had the opportunity to scroll down, worked fine.

But here is my problem, I recently changed my footer, and it now about 70px of height, so I would have to change the CSS properties of every single ones of my pages.

Is there an alternative to this ? Some kind of CSS trick that I could apply only to the CSS of my `div #footer` directly ?

Hoping to hear your suggestions,

Comment: I may be understanding you wrong but can't you just add a margin-top of 70px to your footer div instead of a margin bottom to the other elements?

Comment: I suggest you don't do a fixed footer from a UI/UX stand point unless there is some inherent benefit to the User.

Comment: Stefan : this is indeed the first thing a I tried, but it is not working :/ @haakon319 what's that UI/UX ? thanks

Comment: Yes, @haakon319 is rigth, you shouldn't use a fixed footer that can't be dismissed. But I guess you are not doing your css in a responsive way. If the content of every page you do had an id for example `#wrapper` or a class for example `.content` you could just change the `margin-top` of that id or class.

Comment: yes indeed, sometimes I have a container, and some other times it's only the last element of the page having a defined margin-bottom, I should normalize that but in the meanwhile I was wondering if there was some known css trick to apply this directly to the #footer

Answer (score 2):

You can use in additional div to help you simulate the height of the footer, I use it when I drive my fixed header like this: `<div class="menu-top"></div>` and put it height of my header, in your case I would use a div with class `footer-bottom` and you would place one of 70px height measuring what your footer like this:

Css:

```
.footer-bottom{
    height: 70px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="footer-bottom"></div>
<footer>
...
</footer>
```

it is a simple but effective way, i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution will be adding 'margin-bottom' to your 'body' tag. This will solve your issue.

Comment: this is the solution I'm trying out right now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Put your common css into an external file and include it by every page.

Solution 2: PHP include